# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken is different from GoogleSignInOptions.getIdToken

Tags: android, android-activity, google-authentication, google-signin, android-googleapiclient

Why is it that when using

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, account, "audience:server:client_id:XXX");
```

you get a different ID token than when you retrieve it like this (when using [Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating))

```
GoogleSignInOptions.getIdToken();
```

?

Even weirder is that the id token returned by GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...) can't be validated by the backend (with google certs), while the id token returned by GoogleSignInOptions.getIdToken() CAN be validated.

There's little documentation online, and so far I have no clue how this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following inside [Google's documentation - Authorizing with Google for REST APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth):

> When you want your Android app to access Google APIs using the user's
>   Google account over HTTP, the GoogleAuthUtil class and related APIs
>   provide your users a secure and consistent experience for picking an
>   account and retrieving an OAuth 2.0 token for your app.
>
> You can then use that token in your HTTP-based communications with
>   ***Google API services that are not included in the Google Play services***
>   ***library***, such as the Blogger or Translate APIs.

And you can find their notes at the above link.